# Simple login with Java code - using conditional assignment

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I'm still newbie to java programming. And can anybody tell me what's wrong with the source code? When I run the code, the conditional assignment always outputs "login failed".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProgramBiodataMahasiswa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username, password, output;
        System.out.print("Enter username     : ");
        username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter password     : ");
        password = input.nextLine();
        output = (username=="kesit" && password=="ps123") ? "login successfully" : "login failed" ;
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: try using output = (username.equals("kesit") && password.equals("ps123")) ? "login successfully" : "login failed" ;

Comment: You should also check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) to see why you should use `equals` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Strings ("quest" and "ps123") you shouldn't be using == to check if they equal. This will compare the pointer and due to the fact that String in Java are immutable, the pointers will always be different. Therefore use

```
username.equals("kesit") && password.equals("ps123").
```

That should work!

Answer (score 2):

Use `.equals`

```
output = (username.equals("kesit") && password.equals("ps123")) ? "login successfully" : "login failed" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare strings in Java using `==`.  You should use `equals` method.  e.g. `username.equals("kesit") && password.equals("ps123")`